# How to get attachment's (NSItemProvider) file path in Swift 'Share App Extension'?

Tags: swift, macos, electron

**Note**: I am ***very new*** to Swift programming (2 days only) and I am working on this piece of code as part of an [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org/) project. So please don't mind my ignorance regarding the basics of the language. Thanks.

I have created a Swift app containing a `Share App Extension`.

**Requirements**:

1. The `Share App Extension` should be able to send the `absolute file path` of the shared files to the container app, i.e. If the user selects `a file (abc.txt) from Desktop` in Finder and Shares to my Application, then the Share App Extension should be able to get the file path as

   ```
   /users/userName/Desktop/abc.txt
   ```

   **What I am struggling with here is how to get the file path of the files shared with the Share App Extension. What is the way to get file path of the attachments in `NSExtensionItem` that is available to the `Share App Extension` or is it available from some other object ?**

   (I am able to successfully use `App Groups` to share data between `Share App Extension` and the `Application`)
2. In the final project, the `Share App Extension` becomes a part of an [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org/) project as mentioned earlier.

   **Is there a standard way to share the aforementioned information (file path of the attachments) from the `Share App Extension` to the main/renderer processes of the Electron application.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing the solutions below. Please bear in mind that these might not be the best possible solutions and I am open to suggestions.

#### Solution to Point #1:

**Briefing**: The user selects files from `Finder` to be shared via the `Share App Extension` of the application which is registered with the OS if the `extension context` of the selection matches to that of the `Share App Extension`. Upon doing so, the `Share App Extension` receives the `extension context` alongwith `NSExtensionItem`. The `NSExtensionItem` object contains the `NSItemProvider` object which is the object you'd get for all the files (attachments) shared via the `Share App Extension`.

Now, for each item type that you receive via the `Share App Extension`, after looking for the data that your function recognizes via `hasItemConforminToTypeIdentifier(_:)`, you can use UTI (Uniform Type Identifier) to identify its data.

**Remedy**: Here, the crucial part is to understand that one should be treating their input files as firstly being of the type: `kUTTypeURL`. Then, in the `completionHandler` for the `loadItem` method of the `NSItemProvider` object one would get `NSURL` which is basically the file path I was looking for.

#### Solution to Point #2:

**Briefing**: The `Share App Extension` has the luxury of being written in Swift but the main app in our project does not ! The main application is written in `ElectronJS` which is far far far far from being integratable with Swift ! Except for the fact that the application written in `ElectronJS` has the ability to be packaged in the form of a `dmg` application, there is very little integratability between ElectronJS and Swift as far as the language and framework intertwining is concerned.

**Premise**:
So, the premise is to be able to share the filepaths extracted earlier to be passed from the `Share App Extension` (written in Swift) to the main application (written in ElectronJS). Now, if the main application was a Cocoa application, things would have been much easier. If both of them belong to the same `App group`, then using the Swift APIs they could have read/written synchronously to the Shared Memory. However, the problem arises as those APIs are not available in `ElectronJS`. One remedy can be to run the Swift code in a sandboxed environment within the `ElectronJS` application using nodeJS libraries. However, a sandboxed environment presents its own nuances in data sharing. So, I have kept this approach on hold for now.

So, the approach that I have chosen right now is to use `App Data Directory` to share this intermediary information. The `Share App Extension` would be writing the filepath information in the `App Data` directory of the application and the ElectronJS application would use nodeJs APIs to access this information. Keep in mind that this is a very primitive approach and requires menial efforts but the requirements for this particular case doesn't need stringent security measures anyhow.

However, I am positively looking for a better way to solve Problem #2.

Comment: Re Solution to Point #1: When calling `hasItemConforminToTypeIdentifier` with `kUTTypeURL` or `kUTTypeFileURL` type, you won't get the path if you select a file like PNG. Any suggestion?

Comment: @HonghaoZhang I am not sure why that is happening, but you might want to try `UTI Image Content Types`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mobilecoreservices/uttype/uti_image_content_types

Comment: I want to get the file path for the selected file. I figured it out, I used `kUTTypeItem`, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kuttypeitem and it works. I could get the file path by calling `loadItem...`

Comment: I follow your answer to read a txt file in iOS Files APP through Share Extension and share the txt to my APP. But I failed. Could you help me answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242952/how-to-read-string-in-shared-file-using-share-extension-from-other-app-to-my-app I am new for iOS develop and want to read txt file in Share Extension. Thanks.

Comment: I assume when you refer to a "Share App Extension," you're referring to what apple calls a Share Extension.  It sounds like @AkshayAnurag was able to incorporate one into an electron app.  If so, would be able to explain how?  I've been trying to compile an extension with an empty xcode app project and bring it over to my electron project (putting the .appex into Contents/Plugins/) and it's never being recognized by the system.  If anyone knows how this can be done, please share.  I know I'm not the only one who's trying to find a way.