# How to read the string in an attached file, not sharing the string directly, using Share Extension from other APP to my APP in Swift?

Tags: swift, share-extension

In the following code I can read text in this way and print the text in the code.
[image]

But I do not know how to share txt file as an attachment and read it out in the following code.

```
import UIKit
import Social
import CoreServices

class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {

    private var textString: String?

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here

        if textString != nil {
            if !contentText.isEmpty {
                return true
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
        let contentTypeText = kUTTypeText as String

        for attachment in extensionItem.attachments! {
            if attachment.isText {
                attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentTypeText, options: nil, completionHandler: { (results, error) in
                    let text = results as! String
                    self.textString = text
                    _ = self.isContentValid()
                })
            }
        }
    }

    override func didSelectPost() {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

        print(String(textString!)) // <-- I cannot read txt file and print it

        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
        return []
    }

}


//MARK: NSItemProvider check
extension NSItemProvider {

    var isText: Bool {
        return hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeText as String)
    }

}
```

Is there any method to share the txt file as an attachment in Share Extension?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So now you're asking "how to write a share extension"?

Comment: The code I paste can share text as the picture. But I want to share a whole txt file and read it. I did not search for any code like that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in `info.plist` of your share extension you have to set what type of attachments and how many your extension can get

Example:

```
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>10</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

All keys you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW2)

When your extension recives attachment first you need to check it for type(is it what you are expecting to recive).
And then, in `didSelectPost()` you can get that attachment and do something with it (maybe store it in your app if that's what you want).

[Here](https://medium.com/@abhishekthaplithapliyal/ios-share-extension-930ba1ad3c3d) is nice article about shere extension for photos